# jsdoc @typedef - how to declare function properly?

Tags: javascript, function, jsdoc

Here is my jsdoc declaration.

How should I adjust it, so that `MyNewType.logFirst` property actually references `logFirst` function, which I've annotated below?

```
// my-new-type.js
/**
 * MyNewType definition
 * @typedef {Object} MyNewType
 * @property {function} logFirst
 * @property {function} logSecond
 */

/**
 * @param {number} first
 * @param {number} second
 * @returns MyNewType
 */
module.exports = (first, second) => {
  /**
   * logs first argument
   * @param {number} times
   */
  function logFirst(times) {
    for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
      console.log(first);
    }
  }

  /**
   * logs second argument
   * @param {number} times
   */
  function logSecond(times) {
    for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
      console.log(second);
    }
  }

  return {
    logFirst,
    logSecond
  };
};
```

It's important, that we keep this kind of "factory" structure.

Currently - this is what I receive:
[image]

I want my IDE to bind `MyNewType.logFirst` with `logFirst` definition.

Answer (score 45):

Unless I'm mistaken, I don't see how the upvoted solution could ever work.

There is nothing like `@typedef {MyNewType} MyNewType`in JSDoc, but rather `@typedef {Object} MyNewType` (to define the base type) ([see docs](https://jsdoc.app/tags-typedef.html))

Also, annotations are all mixed up in the given solution. For example, `@param` is only for function parameters and when declaring a specialized function type ([see docs](https://jsdoc.app/tags-param.html))

Last but not least, no offence but the upvoted solution is also wrong because it mixes up the `var MyNewType` type declaration (a function with two parameters and returning an object with two properties) and the actual returned value declaration (the two properties of the said object). In addition to not including the required brackets around the returned type.

EDIT: oh, I forgot that `logFirst` is *not* a `number` but a `Function`, which is another mistake in the solution proposed by the OP colleague.

I really cannot fathom why people would upvote such a broken solution...

Being by no means expert in JSDoc, I however think **the following solution should fix all that**, for new SO visitors:

*(NOTE: I don't see why we would ever need two different typedef for the logFirst and logSecond functions as they have the exact same signature, but JFF I specified both)*

```js
/**
 * Declare our "logFirst" type (which is a function)
 *
 * @callback TypeFnLogFirst
 * @param {number} times
 * @returns {void}
 */

/**
 * Declare our "logSecond" type (which is a function)
 *
 * @callback TypeFnLogSecond
 * @param {number} times
 * @returns {void}
 */

/**
 * Declare our returned type
 * 
 * @typedef {Object} TypeObjTwoFns
 * @property {TypeFnLogFirst} logFirst
 * @property {TypeFnLogSecond} logSecond
 */

/**
 * Declare our "MyNewType" type (which is a function)
 *     with two parameters
 *     and a return value (object literal of type TypeObjTwoFns)
 *     (==> where the magic happens)
 * Note that "[at]typedef Function" is the same as "[at]callback" (as per the docs)
 *
 * @typedef {Function} TypeFnNewType
 * @param {*} first
 * @param {*} second
 * @returns {TypeObjTwoFns}
 */

/** @type {TypeFnNewType} MyNewType */
var MyNewType = (first, second) => {
    /** @type {TypeFnLogFirst} logFirst */
    function logFirst(times) {
        for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
            console.log(first);
        }
    }

    /** @type {TypeFnLogSecond} logSecond */
    function logSecond(times) {
        for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
            console.log(second);
        }
    }

    return {
        logFirst,
        logSecond
    };
};
```

Source: [JSDoc typedef,callback,param](https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html) and [JSDoc member,var,type](https://jsdoc.app/tags-member.html)

Comment: Note that "[at]typedef Function" is the same as "[at]callback" (as per the docs) - does the doc explicitly mention that somewhere? vscode does not seem to treat them the same in terms of intellisense, so just wanted to confirm

Answer (score 4):

Just in case it helps anyone, cause OP is my colleague:

```
    // my-new-type.js
/**
 * MyNewType definition
 * @typedef {MyNewType} MyNewType
 * @param {number} first
 * @param {number} second
 * @property {function} logFirst
 * @property {function} logSecond
 * @returns MyNewType
 */

var MyNewType = module.exports = (first, second) => {
    /**
     * logs first argument
     * @typedef {number} logFirst
     * @param {number} times
     */
    function logFirst(times) {
        for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
            console.log(first);
        }
    }

    /**
     * logs second argument
     * @param {number} times
     */
    function logSecond(times) {
        for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
            console.log(second);
        }
    }

    return {
        logFirst,
        logSecond
    };
};
```

This has worked well for us.

Comment: Shouldn't your typedef be `@typedef {function} MyNewType`? MyNewType isn't defined before the typedef declaration so it can't be used as a type. Afterwards, in a different typedef, it could be though.

Answer (score 3):

**Only if using Typescript** as the type checker, there is a simpler solution IMO:

```
/** @typedef { (first: number, second: number) => 
{logFirst: (time: number) => void, logSecond: (time : number) => 
void}} MyNewType */

/** @type { MyNewType } */
var MyNewType = module.exports = (first, second) => {
   ...
}
```